# Difficulty determining the number of errors that the cyclic code $g(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ of length $6$ can correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, coding-theory

I am trying to figure out the number of errors that the cyclic code $g(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ can correct. I figured out that the generator matrx of the cyclic code is the following:

$$
G = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But I'm not sure how to use that generator matrix to figure out the number of errors it can correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance, the sum of the first two generating vectors is

$(1,1,1,0,0,0) + (0,1,1,1,0,0) = (1,0,0,1,0,0)$

and so the minimum distance is $d\leq 2$. But the code is nontrivial and has $d\geq 2$, i.e., $d=2$. Thus the code can only be used for error detection.

Comment: A non-trivial code can still have $d=1$. But this one has $d=2$. Many ways to see that. One way is to show that a third root of unity $\omega\in\Bbb{F}_4$ is a zero of $g(x)$. As also $\omega^6=1$, it follows that all the polynomials in this code have $\omega$ as a zero. This rules out monomials, i.e. weight one words.